# Wouldn't Thaddeus Bradley having all of the money stuffed into his car demonstrate his innocence?

Tags: plot-explanation, now-you-see-me

For the Four Horseman's final trick, they steal a safe and pack all of the money into Thaddeus Bradley's car in a way that would prevent you from being able to get into the car, let alone drive it. At that precise moment in time the police turn up and arrest him for the theft of the money.

[image]

Wouldn't Thaddeus Bradley having all of the money stuffed into his car demonstrate his innocence? Surely the way these events played out would prevent him from actually being sentenced and thus Dylan's overall goal would fail?

Comment: maybe I'm looking too closely but from what I see this movie just sucked!

Comment: His goal wasn't to frame him in any lasting way, it was to humiliate him and give him something he can never explain that he will fret about for the rest of his life. When questioned by authorities he will be forced to say on record that he doesn't know hew they did a trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I most certainly agree with you; this seems to be not much more than just a *glaring plot-oversight*.  In reality (I surmise), a brilliant robbery will have its share of vanity and stupidity, but I can't think of any reason why a mastermind thief would:

- make his "getaway" car literally unusable
- have all his money be un-contained in a public place (the floor of the parking garage)

So one might ask "why would somebody fill his car up to the brim in cash, then systematically go and open each door and the trunk then step back and savor the view?"

It wouldn't outright imply his innocence, but it would definitely **strongly** suggest he is being framed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it doesn't demonstrate any guilt, but it certain makes it a big pain in the butt for him. Rhodes was in a position to put anything into the investigation report. He obviously would include the fact that Bradley knew every trick the 4H performed, and that could imply some guilt.  So even if it went to trial and was found innocent, or if it never went to trial, there would always be a question of how honest Bradly really was. And it would probably kill his DVD sales. And you know Trexler never paid him after that either.

Of course, none of this is explained. And no, I didn't think it was a great movie either.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that this was not the point. Thaddeus might save himself from going to jail with all the money, but Dylan had 2 goals and he has achieved both.

1. Getting revenge on Thaddeus for the part he played in Dylan's father's demise.
2. Prove that The Horsemen could outsmart Thaddeus, who used to claim magicians were frauds.

The expression on Thaddeus' face when he sees his vehicle loaded with money shows that he realizes he has finally been outsmarted and defeated by a magician.